How to use both sortable and draggable in jQuery UI simultaneously
html:
<div class="item-list" id="list">
  <div class="draggable" data-index="0" draggable="true">Draggable1</div>
  <div class="draggable" data-index="1" draggable="true">Draggable2</div>
  <div class="draggable" data-index="2" draggable="true">Draggable3</div>
  <div class="draggable" data-index="3" draggable="true">Draggable4</div>
  <div class="draggable" data-index="4" draggable="true">Draggable5</div>
</div>
<div class="drawing-board dropzone" id="dropzone">

js:
$("#list").sortable().disableSelection(); 
$('.draggable').draggable({connectToSortable: "#list"});

Demo
Gif Video
Drag the items in the sorting table to the outside and allow them to move freely, and then drag them back to the sorting table to repeat the previous function

Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you wish to drag Sortable items into your dropzone, it must be Droppable. This allow you to Sort the list and then you cna drag an item out of the list and drop it.

Please see this suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zex0L2af/
JavaScript
$(function () {
  $("#list").sortable().disableSelection()
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#list",
  })
  $("#dropzone").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).appendTo("#dropzone").position({
        of: event,
      })
    },
  })
})

When an Item is dragged out and dropped, it is appended to the dropzone and is still draggable. If it is dragged back to the List, the ConnectToSortable preference is used.
